# tyring to use a page loader for my website

Tags: javascript, html, preloader

i am tryin to use a pageloader for my website i am not able to use the javascript in my code if you can help me use the javascript code which is below in my webpage it would be helpful i am in love with this prepage loader. its a handwriting pageloader

pagelooader.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    
    window.onload = function() {
        fadePreLoading();
    };
    function fadePreLoading(){
        document.getElementsByClassName("container-loader-pre")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementsByClassName("container-loader-pre")[0].style.opacity = "0";
        document.getElementsByClassName("container-loader-pre")[0].style.transition = "0.5s";

        var fontSize = 72;
              
        if(window.screen.width < 700){ 
            fontSize = 32;
        }else if(window.screen.width < 1200){
            fontSize= 56;
        }
        var alt = (window.innerHeight/2)-fontSize;

        /****HAND WRITTING EFFECT******/
        var vara = new Vara(
            "#container-pageLoader",
            "./json/Satisfy/SatisfySL.json",
            [
                {
                    text: "Your Name.",//Put your name instead of Shopia Ross
                    y: alt,
                    fromCurrentPosition: { y: false },
                    duration: 1000,
                    id:"draw",
                    autoAnimation:false
                }
            ],
            {
                strokeWidth: 0.5,
                color: "#fff",
                fontSize: fontSize,
                textAlign: "center"
            }
        );
        vara.ready(function(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    vara.draw("draw");
                },500);
                vara.animationEnd(function(i,o){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $(".container-loader").fadeOut('slow');
                        $("body").css({"overflow":"auto"});//when the page is loaded, overflow auto 
                    },200);
                });
        });
    }
});
```

index.html code

```
<div class="loader container-pageLoader">
    <div id="loader">
    </div>
</div>
```